# put user form input into php variable and send mail

Tags: php, forms, variables, user-input

I'd like to send the user a copy of the contact form that they submit. I've got this php code:

```
$formproc->AddRecipient('webmaster@somewhere.com');
```

and this front-end code:

```
<form id='contactsensei' action='<?php echo $formproc->GetSelfScript(); ?>' method='post' accept-charset='UTF-8'>
<fieldset>

<input type='hidden' name='submitted' id='submitted' value='1'/>
<input type='hidden' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputName(); ?>' value='<?php echo $formproc->GetFormIDInputValue(); ?>'/>
<input type='text'  class='spmhidip' name='<?php echo $formproc->GetSpamTrapInputName(); ?>' />

<div class='container'>
    <label for='email' >*E-mail:</label><br/>
    <input type='text' name='email' id='email' value='<?php echo $formproc->SafeDisplay('email') ?>' maxlength="50" /><br/>
    <span id='contactsensei_email_errorloc' class='error'></span>
</div>
```

How do I get the e-mail that the user inputs and add it to the recipients address? I get it in theory, get the user input info and put it in a variable so it end's up something like

```
$uemail = $_POST[uemail];
$formproc->AddRecipient('webmaster@somewhere.com, $useremail');
```

It's obviously not working. Little help. Thanks.

==

Ugh, thought I fixed it because it works, but apparently it works with errors. I have it now with

```
$uemail = $_POST['email'];
$formproc->AddRecipient('webmaster@somewhere.com'); //<<---Put your email address here
$formproc->AddRecipient($uemail);
```

Again it works, but I'm getting this error: 
**Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\wamp64\www\scripts\contact\contactus.php on line 19**

which I have not seen before. My functions are coming from a custom fgcontactform.php if that matters. What / where is it asking me to define?

Comment: $formproc->AddRecipient('$uemail', '$username'); this may help you

Comment: also `$uemail = $_POST['uemail'];`

Answer (score 1):

`uemail` is recognized as a constraint,
to access the $_POST array you must specify a key as a string and it must be the same as your input `name` attribute, so try

```
$uemail = $_POST['email'];
```

and finally pass that variable to the AddRecipient method:

```
$formproc->AddRecipient($uemail);
```

Comment: Works now. Thanks. Is there a way to combine these 2 lines of code?
`$formproc->AddRecipient('webmaster@rovingaikido.com'); 
$formproc->AddRecipient($uemail);`

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add it from post try this:

```
$uemail = $_POST['uemail'];
$formproc->AddRecipient($uemail);
```

Answer (score 0):

Each parameter separated by the comma.If uemail is not a `defined` word then you need to use `$_POST['uemail']`.And you need to use quotes like:

```
$uemail = $_POST['uemail'];
if(isset($uemail))
{
$formproc->AddRecipient($uemail);
}
```